# 3D Vector defined by 3 angles trigonometry components

Tags: trigonometry, vectors, 3d

What I'm looking for is the trigonomery equations to calculate the x, y and z components of a 3D vector. What I mean:

The counterpart formulas for a 2D vector defined by 1 angle:

> $x = \cos(\alpha)$
>
> $z = \sin(\alpha)$

The counterpart for a 3D vector defined by 2 angles:

> $x = \cos(\alpha)  \cos(\beta)$
>
> $z = \sin(\alpha)  \cos(\beta)$
>
> $y = \sin(\beta)$

So what I need is something along the lines of:

> $x = \cos(\alpha)  \cos(\beta)  f(\gamma)$
>
> $z = \sin(\alpha)  \cos(\beta)  g(\gamma)$
>
> $y = \sin(\beta)  h(\gamma)$

where $f(\gamma),g(\gamma),h(\gamma)$ are some functions of $\gamma$.

Comment: Please read [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math expressions.

Comment: any 3-D vector is defined by its magnitude $r$ its angle with $z$ axis and its angle with the $x-y$ plane.

Comment: Although this does not answer your question, you might be interested in Euler angles.

Comment: @MonkeyKing thanks, it's my first time.
@ Lythia Hmm this might actually be usefull, looking into it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the three angles between the vector $\mathbf{v}$ and the coordiante axes, defined by the [direction cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_cosine):

$$
\cos \alpha=\dfrac{\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{i} \rangle}{|\mathbf{v}|}
$$

$$
\cos \beta=\dfrac{\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{j} \rangle}{|\mathbf{v}|}
$$

$$
\cos \gamma=\dfrac{\langle \mathbf{v},\mathbf{k} \rangle}{|\mathbf{v}|}
$$
so that you have:
$$
\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end {bmatrix}=
|\mathbf{v}|\begin{bmatrix}\cos \alpha\\\cos \beta\\\cos \gamma \end {bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for since it appears to take a different type of angles than i have. (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg)